# TNS:Connect timeout occurred BY VPN connecting

Tags: oracle, vpn

I have problem with connected my SQL Developer with database using VPN.
I get error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

I am using Cisto AnyConnect - it is working ok.
Next I create tnsnames.ora like:

```
NAME=
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SOME_IP)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SID = NAME)
)
)
```

When I try connect with this NAME I get error ORA-12170.
Must I configure something else? Maybe something in LISTENER.ORA or in SQLNET.ORA?
When I use command *ipconfig* I know that with using VPN i get IP: 170.30...
Must I using it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your VPN connection is very slow or unstable.

Check these Values in your sqlnet.ora:

```
-SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
-SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT
-SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT
```

Increasing these values should solve problems related to a slow connection.
For informations about those values check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm